# Creating table from Object in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have hardcoded the table in html, I want to generate that table dynamically now in the similar structure with the help of the object. In most of the articles I have looked it shows to dynamically create the table in a slightly different format taking object key as a header but I want to create a table from every object value. For e.g result[0] should be one table, result[1] be another table with any one key-value eg. Tab A as header. How can i do that?

I only want to display the table where ID is equal to 23

```js
result = [{
  "Plan ID": 0,
  "ID": 24,
  "[Plan name]": "Tab A",
  "Emp Only": 133.90,
  "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.30,
  "Emp + Child(ren)": 53.30,
  "Emp + Family": 186.20,
  " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000,
  " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000,
  "Emp ded. / Emp only": 6650,
  "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 13300
}, {
  "Plan ID": 0,
  "ID": 23,
  "[Plan name]": "Tab B",
  "Emp Only": 33.90,
  "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.1,
  "Emp + Child(ren)": 55.30,
  "Emp + Family": 180.8,
  " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000,
  " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000,
  "Emp ded. / Emp only": 660,
  "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500

}]
```

```html
<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2" onchange="myFunction(event)"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$33.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$161.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$53.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$180.8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$3000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$5500</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your expected HTML and are you using the keys as headers?

Comment: Expected Html is the way I have hardcoded  in the question

Comment: no, header should also be the value. for e.g in above object the header for table 1 should be Tab A

Comment: The relationship between the data and the resulting table is not clear. Please clarify what should go with what. Your example data looks duplicated and not unique, this is also confusing.

Comment: yes, i have edited. Could you please see now

Comment: Seems your HTML table does not include all information. There is no way one can see that an amount relates to "Emp only" or "with children". Seems not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this

Using a filter and a few maps, we can create the complete HTML in one go

I also removed your inline event handler and delegated to the main container

Additionally I added the currency and aligned the cells with numbers

```js
result = [{ "Plan ID": 0, "ID": 23, "[Plan name]": "Tab A", "Emp Only": 133.90, "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.30, "Emp + Child(ren)": 53.30, "Emp + Family": 186.20, " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000, " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000, "Emp ded. / Emp only": 6650, "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 13300 }, { "Plan ID": 0, "ID": 23, "[Plan name]": "Tab B", "Emp Only": 33.90, "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.1, "Emp + Child(ren)": 55.30, "Emp + Family": 180.8, " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000, " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000, "Emp ded. / Emp only": 660, "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500 }];

const main = document.getElementById('main');
main.innerHTML = result.map((res,i) => {
  const header = res["[Plan name]"]; // get the plan from the entry
  const idx = i+1;
  return `<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table${idx}" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>${header}<input type="checkbox" id="${idx}" name="table${idx}" value="table${idx}"> </th>
    </tr>
    ${Object.entries(res)  
      .filter(([key,val]) => key.includes('Emp')) // filter the Emp
      .map(([key,val]) => `<tr><td class="amt">$${val.toFixed(2)}</td></tr>`).join('')} 
  </table></div>`}).join('');
  
// replaces your inline event handler using delegation 
main.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type==="checkbox") console.log(tgt.id)
})
```

```css
.amt {text-align:right; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
   
</div>
```

Here more useful perhaps - showing the keys

```js
result = [{ "Plan ID": 0, "ID": 23, "[Plan name]": "Tab A", "Emp Only": 133.90, "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.30, "Emp + Child(ren)": 53.30, "Emp + Family": 186.20, " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000, " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000, "Emp ded. / Emp only": 6650, "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 13300 }, { "Plan ID": 0, "ID": 23, "[Plan name]": "Tab B", "Emp Only": 33.90, "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.1, "Emp + Child(ren)": 55.30, "Emp + Family": 180.8, " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000, " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000, "Emp ded. / Emp only": 660, "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500 }];

const main = document.getElementById('main');
main.innerHTML = result.map((res,i) => {
  const header = res["[Plan name]"]; // get the plan from the entry
  const idx = i+1;
  return `<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table${idx}" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>${header}<input type="checkbox" id="${idx}" name="table${idx}" value="table${idx}"> </th>
    </tr>
    ${Object.entries(res)  
      .filter(([key,val]) => key.includes('Emp')) // filter the Emp
      .map(([key,val]) => `<tr><td>${key}</td><td class="amt">$${val.toFixed(2)}</td></tr>`).join('')} 
  </table></div>`}).join('');
  
main.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type==="checkbox") console.log(tgt.id)
})
```

```css
.amt { text-align:right; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a beginner , It looks little complex to understand. Is there a simpler approach aswell?

Comment: Sure, but that would be too much work.

Comment: In this approach do i need to make any changes in the html code too>?

Comment: And just look line by line to see it is not that complex. It is using nested template literals, a filter and  a map

Comment: But this i can see you are finding the ID with Emp keyword, In that way you are missing 2 rows

Answer (score 1):

You could construct your table using a template-literal and map each key-value pair to a row.

Just pass the record (data), the key for the table name, and the index of appearance in the original array.

Format numbers as currency (`$`) as long as they validate as numbers (`!isNaN`).

You can append the HTML text as a node by calling `insertAdjacentHTML` on the parent (`body`) and passing in `beforeend`.

**Edit:** I added a flag (`INCLUDE_KEYS`) to show/hide key columns for each table. It is optional and currently set to `false`.

```js
const INCLUDE_KEYS = false; // Set to true to reveal keys

const createTableHTML = (data, key, index, includeKeys) => `
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="vertical-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ${includeKeys ? 'colspan="2"' : ''}>
            ${data[key]}
            <input type="checkbox"
                   onchange="myfunction(this)"
                   value="table${index + 1}" /></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        ${Object.keys(data).filter(k => k !== key).map(key => `<tr>
          ${includeKeys ? `<th>${key}</th>` : ''}
          <td>${!isNaN(data[key]) ? `$${data[key].toFixed(2)}` : data[key]}</td>
        </tr>`).join('')}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
`;

const result = [{
  "Plan ID": 0,
  "ID": 23,
  "[Plan name]": "Tab A",
  "Emp Only": 30.5,
  "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 154.1,
  "Emp + Child(ren)": 48.8,
  "Emp + Family": 180.8,
  " max contrib. / Emp only": "None",
  " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": "None",
  "Emp ded. / Emp only": 2750,
  "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500,
  "Emp OOP max / per person": 6850,
  "Emp OOP max / entire famliy": 13700
}, {
  "Plan ID": 0,
  "ID": 23,
  "[Plan name]": "Tab B",
  "Emp Only": 30.5,
  "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 154.1,
  "Emp + Child(ren)": 48.8,
  "Emp + Family": 180.8,
  " max contrib. / Emp only": "None",
  " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": "None",
  "Emp ded. / Emp only": 2750,
  "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500,
  "Emp OOP max / per person": 6850,
  "Emp OOP max / entire famliy": 1555
}];

result.forEach((obj, index) =>
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    createTableHTML(obj, '[Plan name]', index, INCLUDE_KEYS)));
  
function myfunction(checkbox) {
  console.log(checkbox.value);
}
```

```css
.table-wrapper table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.table-wrapper table,
.table-wrapper table th,
.table-wrapper table td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.table-wrapper table thead {
  border-bottom: thick double grey;
}

.table-wrapper table th,
.table-wrapper table td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.table-wrapper tbody td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function myFunction(event) {
    // Do the needful
  }

  var result = [{
    "Plan ID": 0,
    "ID": 23,
    "[Plan name]": "Tab A",
    "Emp Only": 30.5,
    "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 154.1,
    "Emp + Child(ren)": 48.8,
    "Emp + Family": 180.8,
    " max contrib. / Emp only": "None",
    " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": "None",
    "Emp ded. / Emp only": 2750,
    "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500,
    "Emp OOP max / per person": 6850,
    "Emp OOP max / entire famliy": 13700
  }, {
    "Plan ID": 0,
    "ID": 23,
    "[Plan name]": "Tab B",
    "Emp Only": 30.5,
    "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 154.1,
    "Emp + Child(ren)": 48.8,
    "Emp + Family": 180.8,
    " max contrib. / Emp only": "None",
    " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": "None",
    "Emp ded. / Emp only": 2750,
    "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500,
    "Emp OOP max / per person": 6850,
    "Emp OOP max / entire famliy": 1555
  }];

  function makeTable(dataObj, target) {
    target = (target != undefined ? $(target) : $(".table_container"));
    var newTable = $("<table>", {
      id: "table-" + dataObj.ID,
      class: "checkboxdiv"
    }).appendTo(target);
    $("<tr>").appendTo(newTable);
    $("<th>").appendTo($("tr", newTable));
    $("tr > th", newTable).html(dataObj['[Plan name]']);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "checkbox",
      id: dataObj.ID,
      name: "table" + dataObj.ID,
      value: "table" + dataObj.ID
    }).click(function(event) {
      myFunction(event);
    }).appendTo($("tr > th", newTable));
    var exclude = ["Plan ID", "ID", "[Plan name]"];
    $.each(dataObj, function(key, val) {
      if (exclude.indexOf(key) < 0) {
        if (parseInt(val)) {
          newTable.append("<tr><td>$" + parseFloat(val).toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>");
        } else {
          newTable.append("<tr><td>" + val + "</td></tr>");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $.each(result, function(i, items) {
    makeTable(items);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table_container">
  <!-- Example Output
  <table id="table1" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab A<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="table1" value="table1" onchange="myFunction(event)"> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$133.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$161.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$53.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$186.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$3000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$6650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$13300</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table_container">
  <table id="table2" class="checkboxdiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Tab B<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2" onchange="myFunction(event)"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$33.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$161.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$53.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$186.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$3000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$660</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>$13300</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i only need to display value. Not entire key:value pair

Comment: @Nidhi What is a value without a key? I think you need to reevaluate your purpose for creating such a table.

Comment: @Nidhi thats okay, you can simple exclude that portion of the Text, The line would read: `newTable.append("<tr><td>" + val + "</td></tr>");`

Comment: Actually I am creating another table which already have these keys. I just need to display values in this table

Comment: Could you please explain what is this for -----> $(function() {
  function myFunction(event) {
    // Do the needful
  }

Comment: @Nidhi You did not include your myFunction. I solved that in a delegation code

Comment: sorry i dint get it..could u please explain that a bit more

Comment: @Nidhi in your example, you have: `onchange="myFunction(event)"`, I created a placeholder function for this as I do not know what that function is for, so you tell me.

Comment: ohh okay okay...so basically its standard onchange method for detecting change in checkbox

Comment: How can i update it, if i just want to create the table for those data where ID: 23?

Comment: @Nidhi you can just send the Object that contains just that data to the Function.

Answer (score 0):

Now tested, is this perhaps what you're looking for?

```js
const result = [{
    "Plan ID": 0,
    "ID": 23,
    "[Plan name]": "Tab A",
    "Emp Only": 133.90,
    "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.30,
    "Emp + Child(ren)": 53.30,
    "Emp + Family": 186.20,
    " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000,
    " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000,
    "Emp ded. / Emp only": 6650,
    "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 13300
  },
  {
    "Plan ID": 0,
    "ID": 23,
    "[Plan name]": "Tab B",
    "Emp Only": 33.90,
    "Emp + Spouse/Partner": 161.1,
    "Emp + Child(ren)": 55.30,
    "Emp + Family": 180.8,
    " max contrib. / Emp only": 3000,
    " max contrib. / Emp + dependents": 6000,
    "Emp ded. / Emp only": 660,
    "Emp ded. / Emp + dependents": 5500
  }
];

const el = document.getElementById("table_container");
let tables = "";
result.forEach(r => {
  tables += `
    <table class="checkboxdiv">
    <theader>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    </theader>
  `;
  for (let key in r) {
    tables += `
      <tr>
      <td>${key}</td>
      <td>${r[key]}</td>
      </tr>
    `;
  }
  tables += `</table>`;
});
el.innerHTML = tables;
```

```html
<div id="table_container"></div>
```